# How to display image returned in JSON response after uploading

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a page where you can upload images. Everything works except I don't know how to make the page refresh with the new image which is returned in the json response on success. I cant use `location.reload()` because it refreshes the whole app and starts off from the home page. I am using angular2/typescript for my frontend

component.ts (The image value is returned on success)

```
uploadFile(): any {
    let file = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
    if (file.files && file.files[0]) {
        let fileToUpload = file.files[0];
        this.getService
            .uploadImg(fileToUpload)
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                },
                err => {
                    console.log("ERR", err)
                }
            },
            () => console.log("Success")
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to update the `src` attribute of the `img` container. This can be done using the setAttribute function. A primitive example is below.

Javascript

```
uploadFile(): any {
let file = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
if (file.files && file.files[0]) {
    let fileToUpload = file.files[0];
    this.getService
        .uploadImage(fileToUpload, this.id)
        .subscribe(
            response => {
                this.image = response.image;
                document.getElementbyId("image-id").setAttribute("src", "data:image/JPG;base64," + pic.pic );
            },
            err => {
                console.log("ERR", err)
            }
        },
        () => console.log("Success")
    );
}
```

HTML

```
<div *ngIf="pic.pic">
    <img id="image-id" [src]="'data:image/JPG;base64,' + pic.pic" />
</div>
```

Comment: @ghan Please specify the Typescript tag in your original question as it is not vanilla JavaScript

Comment: @ghan `document.getElementById` works perfectly with TS... you simply have to add `dom` in `lib` section in your `tsconfig.json` file or `--lib` param when invoking `tsc` to make it working. Further reading [TS Handbook: compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Answer (score 0):

Heres how I solved it. 
component.ts (The image value is returned on success)

```
pic: any;
upload: any {
    let file = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
    if (file.files && file.files[0]) {
        let fileToUpload = file.files[0];
        this.getService
            .uploadImg(fileToUpload)
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                    //Assign the response here 
                    this.pic = response.image;
                },
                err => {
                    console.log("ERR", err)
                }
            },
            () => console.log("Success")
    );
}
```

The html page

```
    <img [src]="'data:image/JPG;base64,' + pic " />
```